# How to set the path to the classes being tested with Cucumber?

Tags: ruby, windows, cucumber

I've tried following two written guides and one youtube video (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ZmawOCDeyo) and they either skip over an important step (or it just works for them) but not for me.

I have created the following folder structure:

```
RubyBots\
  features\
    step_definitions\
      creating_a_vehicle_for_an_ai_bot_steps.rb
    support\
      env.rb
    creating_a_vehicle_for_an_ai_bot.feature
  vehicle.rb
  vehicle_factory.rb
```

Contents of `creating_a_vehicle_for_an_ai_bot_steps.rb`:

```
Given /^I have vehicle factory$/ do
  @vehicle_factory = VehicleFactory.new
end

When /^I use it to build a basic vehicle$/ do
  @new_vehicle = @vehicle_factory.build
end

Then /^I should have receive a basic vehicle$/ do
  #test @new_vechile
end
```

Contents of `vehicle_factory.rb`:

```
class VehicleFactory
    def initialize(name)
        p name
    end
end
```

Contents of `env.rb` file:

```
require 'vehicle_factory'
require 'vehicle'
```

I execute `Cucumber` (with no parameters) from inside a CMD window inside the `RubyBots` directory and I receive the following error:

```
no such file to load -- vehicle_factory (LoadError)
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
D:/Code/RubyBots/features/support/env.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.0.1/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:143:in `load'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.0.1/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:143:in `load_code_file'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.0.1/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:176:in `load_file'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.0.1/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:78:in `block in load_files!'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.0.1/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:77:in `each'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.0.1/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:77:in `load_files!'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.0.1/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:137:in `load_step_definitions'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.0.1/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:39:in `run!'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.0.1/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:43:in `execute!'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.0.1/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:20:in `execute'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.0.1/bin/cucumber:14:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby192/bin/cucumber:19:in `load'
C:/Ruby192/bin/cucumber:19:in `<main>'
```

If I delete the `env.rb` file from the support directory I get the follow error when running Cucumber:

```
    Scenario: Using a vehicle factory to build a basic vehicle # Features\creating_a_vehicle_for_an_ai_bot.feature:6
Given I have vehicle factory                             # Features/creating_a_vehicle_for_an_ai_bot_steps.rb:1
    uninitialized constant Object::VehicleFactory (NameError)
    ./Features/creating_a_vehicle_for_an_ai_bot_steps.rb:2:in `/^I have vehicle factory$/'
    Features\creating_a_vehicle_for_an_ai_bot.feature:7:in `Given I have vehicle factory'
When I use it to build a basic vehicle                   # Features/creating_a_vehicle_for_an_ai_bot_steps.rb:5
Then I should have receive a basic vehicle               # Features/creating_a_vehicle_for_an_ai_bot_steps.rb:9

Failing Scenarios:
cucumber Features\creating_a_vehicle_for_an_ai_bot.feature:6 # Scenario: Using a vehicle factory to build a basic vehicle
```

I've tried everything I can think of and my google-fu is failing me - I hope it's something non-trivial so I'm not embarrassed, but easy to fix, so that I can move on! :)

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class is called `VehicleFactory` but you're trying to call `vehicle_factory.new` in creating_a_vehicle_for_an_ai_bot_steps.rb.

Also, I believe Cucumber expects a particular directory structure:

```
RubyBots/
  features/
    step_definitions/
      creating_a_vehicle_for_an_ai_bot_steps.rb
    support/
      env.rb
    creating_a_vehicle_for_an_ai_bot.feature
```

You'll need to require your own files from env.rb appropriately. Ruby doesn't work out any paths for you. One way of auto-requiring files based on symbol name (the way Rails does it) is described in [my blog post](http://devblog.aoteastudios.com/2010/03/using-activesupportdependencies-outside.html) (it relies on ActiveSupport 2.3 but should be similar for the current version).

Comment: Thank you! I've fixed that typo now, but I'm still having what appears to be a similar problem.  When I have the above listed `env.rb` file in place I get the same error listed above (when the `env.rb` was in place), when the `env.rb` file is not there I'm getting `uninitialized constant Object::VehicleFactory (NameError)` just below the 'Given I have vehicle factory' line in the Cucumber output.

Comment: I've updated the question with the exact error now.  I've been researching the error and again it seems related to not being able to find the class? (btw, I've been up for over 24 hours now, about to get some sleep - so sorry if this is all down to stupid mistakes).

Comment: I've updated the answer. I think you need to stick with the default directory structure.

Comment: Thanks again for the help @Alex.  I've updated the directory structure (and the question listing above - to reflect that) but I'm still having the issue.  The question is up-to-date with the slightly changed error messages too.  Any further help would be greatly appreciated.  *I just need to get one scenario working and I know I will be back up and running at a good pace!!*

Comment: Have you updated the paths to vehicle.rb and vehicle_factory.rb in your env.rb file?

Comment: Bingo - That was it... In the youtube tutorial there was no path with the require line and I thought it was 'auto worked out', I also tried a number of '../..', '..', '..\..' prefixes relative to the directory structure at the time... but now I've got the `env.rb` file reading: `require 'D:/Code/RubyBots/vehicle_factory'` and it works correctly!  Thank you for your time and effort, definitely worth updating your answer just to reflect that last point that the require statement needs a full path, since the question has been updated and someone else will likely find it.  Thanks again!

Comment: Ruby doesn't work out what to require for you. One way of simplifying requires is described in my blog post (see link in the answer).